# Changing name in CreateDefaultSubobject() stops object from creating its own Mesh

Tags: unreal-engine5

I have a function in my code that creates a UStaticMeshComponent in the Actor’s constructor.

```
VisualMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Mesh"));
```

And it’s works perfect. But as soon as I change name to something else, it stops working. The object stops creating its own Mesh. For example:

```
// NOT WORKING
VisualMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("StaticMesh"));
```

Can you tell me where I`m wrong?

Screenshot where name = L"Mesh":
[image]

Screenshot where name = L"StaticMesh":
[image]

Comment: Have you used the debugger to step through the logic to see what actually happens? Changing the name _should_ not be an issue here.